# Is there an event fired when a .NET collectable assembly is garbage collected (e.g. an Assembly emitted with RunAndCollect)

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, dynamic-assemblies

Is there an event fired when a .NET collectable assembly is garbage collected (e.g. an Assembly emitted with RunAndCollect). Something like AppDomain.AssemblyLoad Event?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any events that tell an application when garbage collection has occurred?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622276/are-there-any-events-that-tell-an-application-when-garbage-collection-has-occurr)

Comment: I'm looking for specifically assembly garbage collections, not just all garbage collections