# Getting Notifications on when GarbageCollector compatcs managed heap arrays

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

as described in the title I would find it super useful to actually know when the GC kicks in, that is, when he begins compressing a before allocated array or other datastructure.

imagine this:

var arr2 = new MyClassA[35];
FillArray(arr2); //some random values

//at this point, lets say: arr2[0]<**byteoffset=32**>arr2[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Peu9o.png)

//use that array...

//some point later GC comes in and b3egins to maybe compress the "arr2" so that the <byteoffset=32> is no longer valid cause he compacted it that way that the elements,
arr2[0]<**byteoffset=8**>arr2[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Peu9o.png) have that distance now!

I would find it very useful for internal algorithms who create some internal chunks based on distance from these fields/array elements, to get notified by the GC at the **moment it is happening** AND **right after it finished** the compacting/compression!

Much thanks already for interesst!

I tried to recieve event on when a potential compaction/compression happens but cant find anything for that.

This is an image I did to sort of explain what i would like [image]to know.

I actually want this to be updated:

```
class Test {
  public int A;
  public double B;
  public string C;
 }

Test[] tests = new[20]; 

ref char first = ref Unsafe.AsRef(tests[0].C[0]);
ref char next = ref Unsafe.AsRef(tests[1].C[0]);

nint diff = Unsafe.ByteOffset(ref first, ref next);
```

//can this value be different when GC compacts or does he even do it?

Comment: Is [this keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/fixed) useful to you? Or perhaps [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.trystartnogcregion?view=net-7.0)?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama to 1) "The address of a fixed, or pinned, variable doesn't change for the duration of the statement" my post says smth else i think. and to 2) for that i am not sure, because it says only to prevent a collection but a "compaction" is not nessecarily a collection, afaik.

Comment: furthermore, even if that would be true that he does prevent compaction, i want to get notified when he compacts! only for that, collections and removing the memory are fine but my problem is that he could come in and COMPRESS the memory/array so that my internal offset computations would get corrupt

Comment: I need to desperately preserve the "Unsafe.ByteOffset(ref arr2[x], ref arr2[x+y])" this is the danger.. 
So i have 2 options:
a) Stop the compaction for the duration when my type is initialized
b) Get notified when he begins and when he finishes the compaction so i can recompute those values..

Comment: Why do you think the GC modifies the layout of an array?

Comment: @KlausGütter  i assumed it when i read about "compacting heap chunks" and so on, so he does not compact arrays like that?

Comment: No, an array stays contiguous in memory. What is compacted is the space in the heap that is no longer used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any events that tell an application when garbage collection has occurred?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622276/are-there-any-events-that-tell-an-application-when-garbage-collection-has-occurr)

Comment: @BurnsBA sadly no, because:

1) Collection is okay, no information needed for this
2) Cleanup is okay, no information needed for this
3) Compacting the array, or compressing it so that : array[0] <-----> array[1] changes in byte-space is NOT okay,  or lets say it is okay, BUT only when I can get notifications on that exact Event, the other events i do not care really :/

Comment: @KlausGütter are really sure about that mate, not pointing out to heap fragmentation or compaction but rather that NEVER touches anymore the space between array elements??

Comment: Yes, really sure. If you want to dive deep, have a look here: https://mattwarren.org/2017/05/08/Arrays-and-the-CLR-a-Very-Special-Relationship/#:~:text=Fundamental%20to%20the%20Common%20Language%20Runtime%20%28CLR%29%20Arrays,%28Intermediate%20Language%29%20instructions%20that%20specifically%20deal%20with%20arrays%3A (has also links to more technical details including source code)

Comment: The offset between `array[1]` and `array[0]` is always equal to the size of the underlying type for value types (struct) or the size of an object reference for reference types (class)

Comment: @KlausGütter  okay that one is good to know thx! 
BUT what if i wanna do this here: "nint diff = 
Unsafe.ByteOffset(ref array[0].Name[0], ref array[0].Name[1])";  
So getting the distance of 2 strings, from each other, will the GC also not touch these, if that is not the case than this post is closed cause i know what ineeded , will look into ur linked source tho

Comment: As string is a reference type, you will always get the size of an object reference here, i.e. 8 (64 bit processes) or 4 (32 bit processes).  Note that this is not the distance of the string objects, but the distance of the string references within the array. Maybe this is what you confuses you.

Comment: @KlausGütter i did not take the distance from the string reference rather their first char! Name[0] to ---> Name[1] cause right now when i do that i get offset for instance, 48 bytes, so 24 chars in difference. this is all good and working its just, can it happen that the GC somehow compress the entire array or even just parts of it so that " sizeof(classA)" (i know u cant do that but he knows intertnaly its size) ends up being smaller or greater even than b4 or even maybe he compacts the other fields of the class so that the distance changed

Comment: Aha. That's a different story. If I get you right, this would not be related to arrays at all, but just two strings somewhere in memory (whether they are referenced from array elements or by some other means would not matter). Can you please [edit] your question so it is absolutely clear what your setup is (e.g. what types are `arr` and `Name` in this example)?

Comment: But i am writing an algorithm who creates chunks dependent on the distance of 2 strings which lies within arrays, the entire thing takes arrays as input, so it matters actually, i wont take just 2 strings as arguments only whole custom class arrays like: Person[] or Whatever[] who have strings as fields

Comment: @KlausGütter  https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/78585  this is my discussion with .net look at the answer of the ms developer "jkotas" who said that arraays can be re -arranged after move and also their space between

Comment: ah and yes btw, strings are handled outside of the class only the ref is stored, i admit i forgot that for a moment., my bad there